# CSS Float not working properly. How to resolve this?

Tags: html, css

Anyone can please tell me why float is not working properly. Why total is not aligned properly. How can I resolve this issue? sorry for my weak English.

HTML:

```
<td class="first" colspan="12" style="text-align: right">
    <div style="margin-top: 7px;"></div> Sub Total: 10000
    <div style="margin-bottom: 7px;"></div>
    <div>- Discount Amount: 12</div>
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #e6eaed; margin-top: 7px; width: 100px; float: right;"></div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold;margin-top: 7px; float: right;">Total: 9988</div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 7px;"></div>
</td>
```

Image:

[image]

[Float Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwJBo.png)

Comment: You may try to add `text-align:right;` instead of float:right.

Comment: Can you try removing the float right? And and display: block, width: 100%; and text-align: right instead.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I tried but it not working can please look at http://vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Printing/Sale_bill

Comment: @Tibs I tried but it not working can please look at vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Printing/Sale_bill

Comment: @ShahRushabh In this link, total is showing good, its on right side. Please do control F5

Comment: Clear your browser's cache. It's working on my end.

Comment: Since you are already use a table, why not a extra table cell??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Floats` are mess if you don't understand there internal logic and allow them to linger without clearing in your divs. You are not clearing `float`, thats why this is happening! :)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="first" colspan="12" style="text-align: right">
    <div style="margin-top: 7px">df</div> Sub Total: 10000
    <div style="margin-bottom: 7px;"></div>
    <div>- Discount Amount: 12</div>
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #e6eaed; margin-top: 7px; width: 100px; float: right;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div> .  <!-- this line is key -->
    <div style="font-weight: bold;margin-top: 7px; float: right;">Total: 9988</div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 7px;"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6emr6cp9/)